# Calculating the real-time displacement of a particule: issues with ifelse, within a conditional for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, if-statement

Being still rather new to R, I struggle with the following problem:
I am looking at several particles moving along the x axis (in reality this is in 3D, but this simplifies matters for our purpose, here). I have a data frame with the each particle's ID and their corresponding position at a given time point.
Here's an example:

```
x.position1 <- c(5, NA, 4, 7, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3)
x.position2 <- c(6, NA, 8, 7, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1)
x.position3 <- c(6, 2, 7, 7, 4, 3, 1, NA, NA, 6)
x.position4 <- c(7, 4, 9, 7, 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 7)
x.position5 <- c(9, 5, NA, 7, 6, NA, 2, 3, 8, 11)
particule.ID <- c(1:10)
df <- data.frame(particule.ID, x.position1, x.position2, x.position3, x.position4, x.position5)
df

   particule.ID x.position1 x.position2 x.position3 x.position4 x.position5
1             1           5           6           6           7           9
2             2          NA          NA           2           4           5
3             3           4           8           7           9          NA
4             4           7           7           7           7           7
5             5           1           2           4           5           6
6             6          NA           1           3           5          NA
7             7           2           2           1           0           2
8             8          NA          NA          NA           0           3
9             9          NA          NA          NA           5           8
10           10           3           1           6           7          11
```

My aim is to calculate the displacement of each particle at each time point i. This displacement is therefore xi - x1. This newly calculated displacement is to be placed in a newly created column.

Here's the script I originally wrote for this:

```
for (i in 1:5){ # iterate for each time point i
  df$Disp <- df[,2+i-1]-df[,2] # create a new column with the calculated displacement for time point i
  nam.Disp <- paste("Disp", i, sep = "") #rename new column Disp+time point number
  names(df)[names(df) == 'Disp'] <- nam.Disp
}

df

particule.ID x.position1 x.position2 x.position3 x.position4 x.position5 Disp1 Disp2 Disp3 Disp4 Disp5
1             1           5           6           6           7           9     0     1     1     2     4
2             2          NA          NA           2           4           5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3             3           4           8           7           9          NA     0     4     3     5    NA
4             4           7           7           7           7           7     0     0     0     0     0
5             5           1           2           4           5           6     0     1     3     4     5
6             6          NA           1           3           5          NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
7             7           2           2           1           0           2     0     0    -1    -2     0
8             8          NA          NA          NA           0           3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
9             9          NA          NA          NA           5           8    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
10           10           3           1           6           7          11     0    -2     3     4     8
```

However, as you may notice in the data frame, sometimes a particle is not detected at i=1, or later. This means that I get a NA value. Therefore, including another loop with IF so that if that 1st time point is NA, R would go to the next time point until it found a non NA value to substract. 
I threfore came up with this, using ifelse instead of IF, since the latter can only deal with one value while my input is actually a column:

```
for (i in 1:5){ # iterate for each time point i
  for (j in 1:5){ # if first time point has no value (NA) scan the row for next time point until an object is detected
    ifelse(!is.na(df[,2+j-1]),
           df$Disp <- (df[,2+i-1]-df[,2+j-1]), # create a new column with the calculated displacement for i time point
           next) # if time point is NA go to next j (next fixed initial time point to test)
  }
  nam.Disp <- paste("Disp", i, sep = "") #rename new column Disp+time point number
  names(df)[names(df) == 'Disp'] <- nam.Disp

}

df

   particule.ID x.position1 x.position2 x.position3 x.position4 x.position5 Disp1 Disp2 Disp3 Disp4 Disp5
1             1           5           6           6           7           9    -4    -3    -3    -2     0
2             2          NA          NA           2           4           5    NA    NA    -3    -1     0
3             3           4           8           7           9          NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4             4           7           7           7           7           7     0     0     0     0     0
5             5           1           2           4           5           6    -5    -4    -2    -1     0
6             6          NA           1           3           5          NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
7             7           2           2           1           0           2     0     0    -1    -2     0
8             8          NA          NA          NA           0           3    NA    NA    NA    -3     0
9             9          NA          NA          NA           5           8    NA    NA    NA    -3     0
10           10           3           1           6           7          11    -8   -10    -5    -4     0
```

Somehow this return wrong values. It looks like the computation occured backwards: Disp1 = x5-x1, Disp2 = x5- x2, Disp3 = x5-x3 etc... while what I expected was: Disp1 = x1-x1, Disp2 = x2-x1, Disp3 = x3-x1 etc.
How can this inclusion of the new for loop and the ifelse function have caused this? What am I doing wrong?
There may be a way to do this manually, but since in reality I have at least 60 time points if not more, the task  would be daunting.

Also, if you think there's a much smarter way to do this, please do share! And if I forgot to include important details that would help you understand better, just let me know.

Many thanks!

Flo

Comment: life will be easier if you set your data to long format

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what do you mean by that?

Comment: Just read about that now. I actually have a version of my data in that format. How do you think this might help?

Answer (score 1):

An example on how to deal with your problem in long format:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(stringr)

df <- setDT(df)
dflong <- melt(df,patterns = "position",id.vars = "particule.ID",value.name = "position")
dflong[,time := str_extract(variable,"[0-9]+$")]  
setkey(dflong,time)
dflong[,displacement := c(NA,diff(na.locf(position,na.rm = F))),by = particule.ID]


    particule.ID    variable position time displacement
 1:            1 x.position1        5    1           NA
 2:            1 x.position2        6    2            1
 3:            1 x.position3        6    3            0
 4:            1 x.position4        7    4            1
 5:            1 x.position5        9    5            2
 6:            2 x.position1       NA    1           NA
 7:            2 x.position2       NA    2           NA
 8:            2 x.position3        2    3           NA
 9:            2 x.position4        4    4            2
10:            2 x.position5        5    5            1
11:            3 x.position1        4    1           NA
12:            3 x.position2        8    2            4
13:            3 x.position3        7    3           -1
14:            3 x.position4        9    4            2
15:            3 x.position5       NA    5            0
.....
```

I use here `data.table`, but the same can be done with `dplyr` and `tidyr`, with `pivot_long`.

```
 melt(df,patterns = "position",id.vars = "particule.ID",value.name = "position")
```

transform your data in long format, with 3 variables : your column name containing the time, the particle.ID, and the position.

I then extract the time with `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
dflong[,time := str_extract(variable,"[0-9]+$")]
```

I order the table along ID and time `setkey(dflong,time)`

I then use `diff(position)` for each `particule.ID` to calculate the displacement. But as I know that I have Nas problems, I use `na.locf` from `zoo`, which allow me to replace the NAs by the last available value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Denis. When I run your code, I have all the same time points grouped together, instead of the particule ID. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: yes. change `setkey(dflong,time)` by `setkeyv(dflong,c("particule.ID","time"))`. You can use also order to reorder the data.table as you want.

Comment: Thanks, this orders the data frame as expected. However, the displacement that the `diff()` function calculates here, is not the one I aim to calculate. My objective is to calculate how far the particule has moved from its first position, at each time point. For most particules this is just a difference with time point 1, but when the particle does not exist then (NA), I need to assigne the next non-NA time point. Is that doable with `diff()` or would you recommend another way?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to calculate the difference of a certain time i to time 1 for each position, you will get `NA` if one of the two numbers is NA.

In your case, we can create a second data frame `df2` which captures changes from time 1 to i for each position 1 until 10.

```
df2<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 4)) 

colnames(df2)<-cbind("chp2","chp3","chp4","chp5")
```

We can capture the differences in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:4) { for (j in 1:10) {
  df2[i][j,]<-df[i+2][j,]-df[2][j,] 
} 

}
```

Now we can put them all in a data frame if we want `df1<-cbind(df,df2)`